# Is Microsoft Cortana API SDK available for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I need to add ASR speech recognition into my app across platforms. It looks like iOS does not let developers have access to speech recognition API and I can't find any information on what Google uses for speech recognition and if it's available to use.

So my question is, is Microsoft Cortana API available for iOS and Android?

Comment: I think stackoverflow should identity who gives down votes so they can be hunted down and forced to give a reason.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Google has extremely recently announced new APIs which can be used to integrate its voice recognition in your apps.

I don't have exact information, but it seems it can primarily be used for searching in your app using the "OK Google" voice command.

If searching is your primary aim then check out the following links-

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6031948?hl=en

http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2014/10/ok-google-voice-search-coming-to-third-party-android-apps/

http://phandroid.com/2014/10/30/ok-google-search-any-app/

Answer (score 1):

Cortana runs only on Windows Phone as of now so having an API would make no sense since there would be no platform to use those APIs on.

This could very well change in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

All you'd really need is some form of web service taking a voice file. Have you searched for any 3rd party speech to text APIs? A quick Google search brings up https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160. I can't vouch for the quality of this, but it's just an example of what could be out there.